# Regular Expressions: Finding lines with 6 or fewer asterisks in them

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression that can find the lines that have 6 or fewer asterisks in them (line should have 1 to 6 asterisks but no more)

For example it should match this whole line

```
...this * is * an * example
```

And it should not match this line

```
**********this is a test ********
```

I do have the following RegEx but it does not take the whole line and it does not work for cases that the line has only one asterisk

```
(\*.*?\*){1,6}.*
```

Comment: Then how about `(\*.*?){0,6}.*` or maybe `(\*.[^\*]?){0,6}.*` to prevent greedy matching?

Comment: Something tells me there are more straightforward ways to do this than spending any effort on finding the correct regex.

Comment: @CompuChip `[^\*]` is definitely required, otherwise stray asterisks get consumed by the wildcard once 6 have been seen.

Comment: What language or tool are you using ?

Comment: @Sniffer I am using grep but any language should do. I am basically interested to know if it is at all possible to do by using pure RegEx than using Perl or anything like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
^(?!(?:[^*\r\n]*\*){7})(?=[^*\r\n]*\*).*
```

- `^` Matches the start-of-line. **Note:** Turn multi-line mode on in your regular expressio so that `^` matches the start of each line and not the start of string.
- `(?:[^*\r\n]*\*)`: Matches zero or more characters which are not stars `[^*]*` nor carriage returns `\r`, nor newlines `\n` then it matches the star `*`.
- `{7,}`: Matches the preceding 7 or more times.
- `(?!...)`: Makes the match fail in case the previous pattern actually match 7 or more stars.
- `(?=[^*\r\n]*\*)`: Makes sure the line contains at least one star.
- `.*`: If the negative look ahead succeeded, the this matches the entire line.

**NOTE:** I have updated the demo link too.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fI1mJ5)

Comment: @Mark I have edited the expression a little bit and now it works correctly, check the demo link I posted.

Comment: Not bad. The `,` is unnecessary, so is the final `.*`

Comment: @pguardiario You are correct about the `,` as it takes out some performance, on the other hand the `.*` is necessary if you want to match the contents of those lines.

Comment: Close, but `^(?!(?:[^*\r\n]*\*){7}).*` does not guarantee that there is at least one asterisk (one of the stated requirements).

Comment: @Sniffer I have to agree with ridgerunner. The regex also matches lines that do not have an asterisk

Comment: @Mark I have read the question several times, but I couldn't find a place where you said that you want at least one star in the line. Anyway the needed modification is tiny and I have made it, please check edit.

Comment: @Sniffer I cannot deny that I have been battling with this problem on and off for a couple of days now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just count the asterisks in the string. In Perl this would be

```perl
my $number =()= $string =~ /\*/gi;
# or...
$number = ($string =~ tr/\*//);  # only works for single characters..

if ($number <= 6) {
   print "Match:".$string."\n";
}
```

PHP has substr_count() or preg_match_all() which can probably do the job.

Comment: I certainly appreciate the solution but I am interested to know if this is possible in pure regex

Comment: That regex does not work as it seems it looks for asterisks that are next to each other

Comment: Even with a /g flag? Apologies I'm not at a PC with Perl installed to test my theories! :-(

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your tag votes I am guessing you are using `R` and this is super easy with the `stringr` pacakge using `str_count()`...

```
#  Your data
x <- c( "...this * is * an * example" , "**********this is a test ********" )

#  Load required package
require( stringr )

#  Count instances of * (note the pattern is a regex so you must escape *) and compare to condition '<= 6'
idx <- str_count( x , "\\*" ) <= 6
# [1]  TRUE FALSE

#  Subset data vector
x[ idx ]
#[1] "...this * is * an * example"
```

Or a base R example to count the matches using `gregexpr()` and `regmatches()`....

```
sapply( regmatches( x , gregexpr( "\\*" , x ) ) , length ) <= 6
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's  how I'd write it:

`/^[^*]*(?:\*[^*]*){1,6}$/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it seems to work :)

```
^(?=^.*\*.*$)(?!(.*\*){7,}).*$
```

of course it's expensive :( but it's regex :)